# Can anyone help me what is the issue going on with my code? i was trying to initiate a test using internet explorer and it failed

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
4.0.0.0
Listening on port 31935
Only local connections are allowed

Comment: If possible, could you provide the code example that we can reproduce this issue? This will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Selenium Internet Explorer Configuration

Internet Explorer with Selenium automation is one of the supported drivers. Personally, I would **recommend a Chrome Driver or a FireFox driver**, but for Internet Explorer Driver, make sure the *version of your browser matches the version of the installed driver*.

More information can be found here: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-tests-on-internet-explorer/